# Why is tikz boxes started on different y-levels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I've this code that suppose to draw a schedule/schema/timetable

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=5mm, bottom=5mm, left=5mm, right=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

%Options for timetable contents
\def\firsthour{8}
\def\lasthour{17}

%Options for timetable drawing
\def\daywidth{3.4cm}   %approx \textwidth / 6
\def\hourheight{2.2cm} %approx \textheight / (\lasthour - \firsthour + 1)

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=\daywidth, y=-\hourheight,
    block/.style={
        draw, text width=\daywidth, minimum height=\hourheight, inner sep=0pt, align=flush center
    },
    hour/.style ={block, fill=yellow!40, font=\bfseries\Large,
        text width=0.6*\daywidth, xshift=0.2*\daywidth},
    day/.style  ={block, fill=yellow!40, font=\bfseries\Large,
        minimum height=0.5*\hourheight, yshift=-0.25*\hourheight},
    week/.style ={block, fill=yellow!40, font=\bfseries\Large,
        minimum height=0.5*\hourheight, yshift=-0.25*\hourheight,
        text width=0.6*\daywidth, xshift=0.2*\daywidth},
    name/.style ={font=\normalsize},
    hours/.style={minimum height=#1*\hourheight}
]\tikzset{ AtHome/.style={block, fill=red!20, draw=red!50!black, thick} }
\tikzset{ AtJobCoach/.style={block, fill=green!20, draw=green!50!black, thick} }
\tikzset{ PersonalCoaching/.style={block, fill=blue!20, draw=blue!50!black, thick} }
\tikzset{ SYV/.style={block, fill=cyan!20, draw=orange!50!black, thick} }
\tikzset{ LUNCH/.style={block, fill=orange!20, draw=purple!50!black, thick} }


\draw[help lines, xshift=0.5*\daywidth, yshift=0.5*\hourheight]
    (0, \firsthour) grid [xstep=\daywidth, ystep=\hourheight] (5, \lasthour);

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\secondhour{\firsthour + 1}
\foreach \end[remember=\end as \start (initially \firsthour)] in {\secondhour, ..., \lasthour} {
    \node[hour] at (0, \start) {\start--\end};
}

\node[week] at (0, \firsthour-1) {v.40};
\node[day] at (1, \firsthour-1) {{\small 30/09} Måndag};
\node[day] at (2, \firsthour-1) {{\small 01/10} Tisdag};
\node[day] at (3, \firsthour-1) {{\small 02/10} Onsdag};
\node[day] at (4, \firsthour-1) {{\small 03/10} Torsdag};
\node[day] at (5, \firsthour-1) {{\small 04/10} Fredag};

\node[AtHome, hours=4] at ( 2 , 8 ) {
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut TEXT 4 hours
};
\node[LUNCH, hours=1] at ( 2 , 12 ) {    
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut LUNCH
};
\node[AtJobCoach, hours=3] at ( 2 , 14 ) {
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut TEXT 3 hours
};
\node[AtHome, hours=1] at ( 2 , 16 ) {
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut TEXT 1 hour
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The row of daynames (Måndag, Tisdag, Onsdag, etc.) all works fine and are in level, but the node "TEXT 4 hours" starts way above the day names making the whole timetable to look strange. Of course I can change the 8 in (2, 8) to make it level correctly, but that shouldn't be needed and I can't figure out a system for how much I should correct the 8 to be able to get a good schedule.

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the nodes are centered around the coordinate you specify. If you add `anchor=north,yshift=0.5*\hourheight` to the `block` style, and perhaps modify the other yshifts in the styles (I lost track a bit, but I can highlight the changes later, if you like).

With the code below you specify the start hour of each block, hence the change from `14` to `13` for  the `AtJobCoach` one. I haven't tested anything else than what was already in the code, so if anything fails miserably, let me know.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=5mm, bottom=5mm, left=5mm, right=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} % loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

%Options for timetable contents
\def\firsthour{8}
\def\lasthour{17}

%Options for timetable drawing
\def\daywidth{3.4cm}   %approx \textwidth / 6
\def\hourheight{2.2cm} %approx \textheight / (\lasthour - \firsthour + 1)

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=\daywidth, y=-\hourheight,
    block/.style={
        draw, text width=\daywidth, minimum height=\hourheight, inner sep=0pt, align=flush center, anchor=north, yshift=0.5*\hourheight
    },
    hour/.style ={block, fill=yellow!40, font=\bfseries\Large,
        text width=0.6*\daywidth, xshift=0.2*\daywidth},
    day/.style  ={block, fill=yellow!40, font=\bfseries\Large,
        minimum height=0.5*\hourheight, yshift=-0.5*\hourheight,},
    week/.style ={block, fill=yellow!40, font=\bfseries\Large,
        minimum height=0.5*\hourheight, yshift=-0.5*\hourheight,
        text width=0.6*\daywidth, xshift=0.2*\daywidth},
    name/.style ={font=\normalsize},
    hours/.style={minimum height=#1*\hourheight},
    AtHome/.style={block, fill=red!20, draw=red!50!black, thick},
    AtJobCoach/.style={block, fill=green!20, draw=green!50!black, thick},
    PersonalCoaching/.style={block, fill=blue!20, draw=blue!50!black, thick},
    SYV/.style={block, fill=cyan!20, draw=orange!50!black, thick},
    LUNCH/.style={block, fill=orange!20, draw=purple!50!black, thick}
]


\draw[help lines, xshift=0.5*\daywidth, yshift=0.5*\hourheight]
    (0, \firsthour) grid [xstep=\daywidth, ystep=\hourheight] (5, \lasthour);

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\secondhour{\firsthour + 1}
\foreach \ending[remember=\ending as \start (initially \firsthour)] in {\secondhour, ..., \lasthour} {
    \node[hour] at (0, \start) {\start--\ending};
}

\node[week] at (0, \firsthour-1) {v.40};
\node[day] at (1, \firsthour-1) {{\small 30/09} Måndag};
\node[day] at (2, \firsthour-1) {{\small 01/10} Tysdag};
\node[day] at (3, \firsthour-1) {{\small 02/10} Onsdag};
\node[day] at (4, \firsthour-1) {{\small 03/10} Torsdag};
\node[day] at (5, \firsthour-1) {{\small 04/10} Fredag};

\node[AtHome, hours=4] at ( 2 , 8 ) {
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut TEXT 4 hours
};
\node[LUNCH, hours=1] at ( 2 , 12 ) {    
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut LUNCH
};
\node[AtJobCoach, hours=3] at ( 2 , 13 ) {
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut TEXT 3 hours
};
\node[AtHome, hours=1] at ( 2 , 16 ) {
    \nodepart[name]{one} \strut TEXT 1 hour
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I changed the loop variable from `\end` to `\ending`. Even though it obviously doesn't break `\end`, seems better to stay away from such a basic macro, just as a matter of principle.